# Why is the web browser not setting my cookie?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, cookie-session

I am using the cookie-session package.

```
app.use(
  cookieSession({ 
    signed: false, 
    secure: false 
  })
);
```

When a user signs up, I set the session property to an object.

```
req.session = { jwt: userJwt };
```

The cookie is successfully sent to the browser, as seen in [Response Cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ9q2.png).

The browser does NOT set the cookie.

My frontend runs on http://localhost:1234 and my server runs on http://localhost:3000.

I am NOT currently proxying requests in development i.e. to sign up I hit http://localhost:3000/api/users/signup.

Comment: How are you verifying it not being set? Those are different origins due to the different ports

Comment: The cookies tab and when I send a request to my server the cookie is not present on the request headers

Comment: @HugoJavadi-Babreh, can you add the code that show how you are generating a JWT?